# Send Tron transaction with Ethereum compatible address

Tags: nethereum, tron

Is it possible to make a transaction for the Tron network with the Nethereum library?

As you know, Tron addresses can be converted to Ethereum format with the help of the following site
https://tronscan.org/#/tools/code-converter/tron-ethereum-address

For example, public address
TA3Pynm9EUEheHYoXshViEFMSxm2vNNN4s

In Ethereum format, it is as follows:
0x00CAD3F26E3E2D7D777354FFC9CF51D581D0F17C

I have been able to get the balance of the wallet using the public address in the Ethereum format with the Nethereum library

`var account = new Account(privateKey);`

`var web3 = new Web3(rpcClient);`

`var contractAddress = ConvertTronToEthereumAddress("TR7NHqjeKQxGTCi8q8ZY4pL8otSzgjLj6t");`

`var service = web3.Eth.ERC20.GetContractService(contractAddress);`

`Console.WriteLine(await service.BalanceOfQueryAsync(account.Address));`

But I couldn't make a transfer transaction.

Thank you in advance